# Eigen indexing, update all column of a specific row

Tags: c++, eigen

Let say I have an `ArrayXXf` (or `MatrixXf`) `m`. In each iteration of a for loop, I want to fill `m` row-wise with a `VectorXf`.

```
Eigen::ArrayXXf m(5, 5);

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    Eigen::VectorXf vec(5);
    vec << i, i + 1, i + 2, i+3, i+4;

    //fill m row wise
    // in matlab I will do something like m(i,:) = vec; 
    // in numpy this will looks like m[i:] = vec;
    // that means when i is 0 m looks like 
    //          [ 0 1 2 3 4 5
    //           -  - - - - -
    //           -  - - - - -
    //           -  - - - - -
    //           -  - - - - -]
}
```

How can I achieve that in Eigen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use block() function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Eigen::ArrayXXf m(5, 5);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        Eigen::VectorXf vec(5);
        vec << i, i + 1, i + 2, i+3, i+4;

        m.block(i, 0, 1, 5) << vec.transpose();
    }

    std::cout << m << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0 1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5
2 3 4 5 6
3 4 5 6 7
4 5 6 7 8
```

**Edit:**

There is one simpler alternative also: row() function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Eigen::ArrayXXf m(5, 5);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        Eigen::VectorXf vec(5);
        vec << i, i + 1, i + 2, i+3, i+4;

        m.row(i) = vec.transpose();
    }

    std::cout << m << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0 1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5
2 3 4 5 6
3 4 5 6 7
4 5 6 7 8
```

P.S. transpose() is required because Eigen::VectorXf by default is a column vector, **not** a row vector.

Comment: excellent, thanks. The second alternative is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 5):

To simplify @Kunal's answer, you can directly modify rows (or columns) of an Array (or Matrix) without creating a temporary vector. In your example you can use `.setLinSpaced()`:

```
Eigen::ArrayXXf m(5, 5);

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    m.row(i).setLinSpaced(i,i+4); //.col(i) would be slightly more efficient
}
```

or use the comma initializer:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    m.row(i) << i, i+1, i+2, i+3, i+4;
}
```

Comment: I think the OP's question included filling `Eigen::ArrayXXf` using `VectorXf`. I haven't created any temporary vector.

Comment: @KunalPuri IMO, it is a bit unclear what the OP really needs. The `vec` variable in the question is a temporary which, as it is, is not necessary. If actually some complicated calculations happen with `vec` it could very likely be worth having a temporary for that.

Comment: This would not have solve my problem, because in my real case scenario, the array `m` must be filled using a vector which is created by vertically concatenating column of a image.
Creating the vector using `i` was for demonstration purposes.